# Where do you get TFS 2015 tfs_sharePointExtensions.exe

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2013, tfs-2015

Looking at this for setting up SharePoint extension for TFS 2015:

https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-tw/docs/setup-admin/tfs/install/sharepoint/setup-remote-sharepoint

I have remote SharePoint servers. I'm just looking to update the extension installed from the TFS 2013 version to the TFS 2015 version.

It mentions the following, but I can't find the EXE:

> Tip:
>   If you don't want to install all of Team Foundation Server on the server that is running SharePoint Products, launch the **tfs_sharePointExtensions.exe** file from the SharePoint Extensions folder to install only the Team Foundation Server Extensions for SharePoint Products.

Really don't want to install the Full TFS Admin console if I can just install the extension alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not work with TFS2015 any more.

> With TFS 2015 the installation media **no longer includes the
>   SharePoint installation bits nor a separate
>   `tfs_sharePointExtensions.exe` installer**.
>
> To integrate your Team Foundation Server with SharePoint, you must
>   **run the Team Foundation Server installer on the SharePoint server** and then configure TFS Extensions for SharePoint. The integration
>   process itself remains the same.

More details you can refer the *Scenario 2: [TFS integrated with remote SharePoint Server.]* in this blog [Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 – SP integration.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/09/10/team-foundation-server-tfs-2015-sp-integration/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Microsoft should update their site to say that instead of saying using the EXE.